# Lambda event filtering for DDB trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

My usecase is to filter events from DDB with filter condition present on both OldImage AND NewImage.

Filter that I have added -

```
{
  "dynamodb": {
    "NewImage": {
      "DriftResult": {
        "BOOL": [
          true
        ]
      }
    },
    "OldImage": {
      "DriftResult": {
        "BOOL": [
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to filter events such that DriftResult if false in OldImage AND true in NewImage .

However , events are being filtered out only on basis of 1st condition , i.e, when DriftResult is true in NewImage irrespective of value in OldImage .

Can anyone help how can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the "dynamodb" key as part of the second expression you want to be ANDed. The correct format of your filter would be:

```
{ 
  "dynamodb": { 
    "NewImage": { 
      "DriftResult": { 
        "BOOL": [ 
          true 
        ] 
      } 
    } 
  }, 
  "dynamodb": { 
    "OldImage": { 
      "DriftResult": { 
        "BOOL": [ 
          false 
        ] 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```